# He didn't go to the store, but to the gym

Tags: negation

To say that he went to the gym and did not go to the store, is it OK to say, "He didn't go to the store, but to the gym"?

It seems that this would mean, "He didn't go to the store, but [he didn't go] to the gym," which was not the intended claim.

Likewise:

He did not marry Peggy, but Sue. <-> He married not Peggy but Sue.

He didn't listen to my lecture, but to his iPod. <-> He listened not to my lecture but to his iPod.

Comment: It's certainly okay to use this form, but I think in general it's only suitable for contexts where the first option is in fact the *default*. That's to say, contexts where *not X, but Y* effectively means *not X,* **as expected,** *but Y*.

Comment: By "this form" did you mean "married not X, but Y" or "didn't marry X, but Y." It's the latter that is at issue.

Comment: I think there is no meaningful distinction to be made between *married not X, but Y* and *didn't marry X, but Y*. They are trivial stylistic variants. In your second sentence above, the inclusion of square-bracketted *[he didn't go]* makes no sense to me, and if by **<->** you mean *is not the same as* then I think you are simply mistaken.

Comment: By <-> I just meant "Compare these two." But yes, I do think there is a difference. And the brackets were just the unstated parts that are needed to parse/diagram the sentence. In other words, because the negation is in the verb phrase, I do not see why its scope would not extend over both disjunctions, _going to the store_ and _going to the gym_.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. The murderer was not a man, but a woman!

Comment: @Sam: Proves my point. You wouldn't normally say *The murderer was not a woman, but a man!* unless you'd previously been thinking it was a woman, for some reason. *But* in this usage implies *but, contrary to expectations*.

Comment: @John: To repeat - your square-bracketted *[he didn't go]* makes no sense. Other than that, all the variations you have presented are equally valid, and there is no difference in meaning or grammaticality between the paired alternative ways of using "but". If you think there *is* a difference, please say what you think that difference is, so it can be refuted.

Comment: The scope of negation in language is often difficult, and sometimes different from what a formal logical analysis would suggest. I long had trouble with "All that glisters is not gold", until I realised that what a sentence means is not what some logician would have it mean, but what it _does_ mean.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I agree, I was just providing an example.

Comment: The "didn't do X but Y" will be understood, but "did not X but Y" is clearer and thus preferred.  A prescriptivist would probably say that the first is wrong, but nobody would say the second is.

Comment: @Colin: Agreed linguistic negation can get tricky. Anyone who ain't got no problems with it, especially in speech, is probably not paying attention. But I still have no idea why OP thinks the choice of different phrasings involving "but" has any grammatical or semantic significance.

Comment: @Monica: [we will not ask for money, but for books](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=6hRHAAAAMAAJ&q=%22not+ask+for+money+but%22&dq=%22not+ask+for+money+but%22&hl=en&ei=C4qlTr3PDdSX8gPbj6n2BQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&redir_esc=y). Are you going to say that's only acceptable because it happens to repeat the word "for"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: In "The murderer was not a man, but a woman" the comma is not required. That's a straightforward compound object of a shared predicate. My concern is the one _OED_ addresses in III s.v. _but_, where the verbal phrase cannot be shared by the disjuncts.

Comment: @John P: oic. I think then you're just bothered about what degree of ellipsis is "acceptable" when using *but* in this way. To which my answer is it's a matter of style. In my comment two above this, for example, I don't care whether the second "for" is ellided or not, and I wouldn't accept any grammarian's "rule" that tried to tell me what the limits are.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: "Clearer and thus preferred". By whom? Plenty of people prefer to use phrases that happen not to be clearer than alternatives.

Comment: @Colin, if the goal is communication then clarity seems preferable.  If the goal isn't communication but art (e.g. some poetic constructs), then that might not matter as much.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: "_Seems_" preferable, may be. But the observable fact is that people often choose forms and structures which are objectively less clear than their alternatives, not necessarily for poetic or rhetorical reasons, and yet achieve quite satisfactory communication thereby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Barry England and OED, I see what is going on.

The construction is not a compound object or even a compound predicate. It is a compound sentence. That's why there is and rightly should be a comma before "but." And that's why rules for parsing compound objects and compound predicates don't apply.

What comes before the ", but" is a complete independent clause. What comes after the ", but" is also an independent clause but a highly contracted one. The reader is left to supply the missing pieces, using as clues the sense, the indication provided by the adversarial conjunction, case, gender, and any other words the author has supplied.

> Joe didn't marry Peggy, but Sue.

From word order and knowing what we do about marriage, we supply the missing parts and understand this compound sentence:

> Joe didn't marry Peggy, but (Joe did marry) Sue.

OED has this example:

> Thou hast not lied unto men, but unto God.

and expands it to:

> Thou hast not lied unto men, but (thou hast lied) unto God.

The "unto" helps. This:

> Peter didn't invite Paul, but John.

might slow us down, but we can read through this without hesitation:

> Peter didn't invite him, but her.

It makes sense that in Latin, a highly inflected language, this construction is more common than in English.

So the construction is as valid as any other contracted construction and, like other contracted constructions, is most effective when the chance for ambiguity is not significant and a little mental work, but not much, is required from the reader.

Bad idea:

> Bob didn't call Joe today, so Tom didn't send the report to Frank, but Mary.

Comment: Also note that this ellipsis works only with negative statements in the first part (and positives in the second: therefore it should not be possible to misinterpret it)

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, "Joe didn't marry Peggy, but Sue" may also be written "Joe married not Peggy but Sue".

Answer (score 3):

I think the OED’s definition 23 of *but* might cover it:

> As adversative conjunction, appending a statement contrary to, or
>   incompatible with, one that is negatived:  On the contrary. = German
>   *sondern*.

Comment: Ah yes. "In a compound sentence, connecting the two co-ordinate members; or introducing an independent sentence connected in sense, though not in form, with the preceding. In a compound sentence the second member is often greatly contracted, as in ‘Thou hast not lied unto men, but (thou hast lied) unto God’." This is my case. What follows the comma (why it is there?) is a greatly contracted clause connected in sense but differing in form from the preceding. And sure enough, OED added the parenthetical.

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly valid. The use of 'but' indicates a contrast between clauses.  If you were using 'and' then your assesment of the literal meaning would be correct, but 'but' creates a situation where the meaning of the second part of the sentence is understood to be the opposite of the first part.

From the link below:

> To suggest in an affirmative sense what the first part of the sentence
>   implied in a negative way (sometimes replaced by on the contrary):
>   "The club never invested foolishly, but used the services of a sage
>   investment counselor."

http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/conjunctions.htm#but

Comment: This case is different. The subject is _The club_. It is followed by two predicates -- _never invested foolishly_, _used the services of a counselor_ -- separated by the conjunction _but_. That's a fine construction of two predicates sharing one subject. There is a little ambiguity about the scope of the negation, I guess, but there is at least one reading that presents no problem. (BTW, the comma should not be in there.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the sentence is awkward. I think it certainly communicates the intention, but it grates a little. The use of "but" indicates a contrast between the first and second choice of destination which is why we understand the meaning, but the sentence is practically begging for the word "instead" at the end.

For sure, even with instead at the end, it would be much better phrased differently. Such as:

```
He didn't go to the store, instead he went to the gym.
He went to the gym instead of the store.
Instead of the store he went to the gym.
```

And so forth.

Comment: My question is one of grammar. I certainly understand the intention of "He didn't go to the store, but to the gym" and I would even use the construction in conversation. But I think its literal meaning is not the intended one. Is it? I wonder if your addition of "instead" changes how the sentence would be parsed.

Comment: This construction
**[subject] [verb phrase] [1st predicate object] [conjunction] [2nd predicate object]** 
is a short way of saying 
**[subject] [verb phrase] [1st predicate object] [conjunction] [subject] [verb phrase] [2nd predicate object]**

If that rule applies, then 
**[he] [did not marry] [Peggy] [but] [Sue]** 
means the same as 
**[he] [did not marry] [Peggy] [but] [he] [did not marry] [Sue]**

Why would that rule not apply?

Comment: @JohnP.McCaskey: Where did you get that rule from? It's obviously not a valid rule in general, since it doesn't apply here.

Comment: @JohnP.McCaskey The thing is that when there is an ellipsis, as there is here, you need to use intelligence and the context to work out what the ellipsis is. It is not really a grammatical thing, it is more at the level of semantics. The use of a contrasting conjunction tells us that the part on the left does not match the part on the right.